# fetch_array errors when querying data using mysqli_query

Tags: php

If I try to create a sql query such as this:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID='$delID'") or die(mysqli_error());
$getQuery = $connection->query($sql2);
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
    $childID = $row['ID'];
    $parentID = $row['PROD_ID'];
    $childName = '../ProductImages/ChildImages/'.$parentID . "_".$childID.".jpg";
    unlink($childName);
}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on null in

If I run and store the query to `$sql` like this:

```
$sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID = '$delID'") or die(mysqli_error());
$getQuery = $connection->query($sql2);
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
    $childID = $row['ID'];
    $parentID = $row['PROD_ID'];
    $childName = '../ProductImages/ChildImages/'.$parentID . "_".$childID.".jpg";
    unlink($childName);
}
```

The query run smoothly without any issues.

What is the problem why doesn't the first option works?

Comment: you are mixing object-oreinted approach with procedural approach. don't do that

Comment: Your query not properly called `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID='$delID'" ` instead of this `$sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID='$delID'") or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this bit of code?

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID='$delID'") or die(mysqli_error());
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
$getQuery = $connection->query($sql2);
                         ^^^^^
```

You're actually querying twice, that's why you're getting the error.

Plus, the `or die(mysqli_error())` belongs *after* the query call and it requires a db connection as the argument.

I.e.: `or die(mysqli_error($connection))`.

So you'd do the following to check if the query failed:

```
if(!$getQuery){

    echo "Error: " . die(mysqli_error($connection));

}
```

Rewrite:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM CHILD_IMG WHERE PROD_ID='$delID'";
$getQuery = $connection->query($sql2);
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
    $childID = $row['ID'];
    $parentID = $row['PROD_ID'];
    $childName = '../ProductImages/ChildImages/'.$parentID . "_".$childID.".jpg";
    unlink($childName);
}
```

You're also open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (mysqli)
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (PDO)

Note: If you intend on going with PDO, remember to not mix the different MySQL APIs.

Comment: Ahh i see. So if i want the first option to work i need to do $getQuery = $connection($sql2);?

Comment: More descriptive.+1.But add the solution. you tell the cause but din't added solution

Comment: @Fred-ii-  the one which works also have `or die(mysqli_error());` unnecessarly

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks, give me a minute. I noticed your new comment also.

Comment: @Fred ii Im using my second option but would be nice why the first one doesnt work.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  it need to be:- `if(!$getQuery){ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $connection->error); }`. I know what you have there is also correct.

Comment: @LukeDS Both queries are the same, but I added a new bit of code just now.

Comment: thanks, for the explanation any chance i can get a like in the question?

Comment: @LukeDS You're welcome Luke, *cheers* ;-) Btw, I added a few more links for you to look into, in regards to prepared statements. You don't want your db to disappear.